# some usage of of() was deprecated in rxjs ~7.0.0-alpha.0 version

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In repository of rxjs I find this string:

```
/** @deprecated remove in v8. Do not use generic arguments directly, 
allow inference or cast with `as` */
export function of<T>(value: T): Observable<T>;
```

But can't find an example, how to rewrite code such as:

```
concatMap(response => of(response).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectPatientQuestions))),
  ))
```

in new version of lib. Can anyone provide me an example for such case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such deprecation for the function signature that you're referring too. It is the signature **before** that line that is deprecated.

```js
/** @deprecated remove in v8. Do not use generic arguments directly, allow inference or cast with `as` */
export function of<T>(): Observable<T>;
```

The above has been replaced with:

```js
export function of(): Observable<never>;
```

You can not infer a *generic* type from an observable that emits nothing, but the API previously did this.

For example;

```js
of<boolean>().pipe(
   tap(value => value = true)
   /// ^^^^^ TypeScript thinks value is of type boolean so the assignment is allowed
);
```

The above is not correct, because the observable never emits a boolean value.

Where as, the following will tell TypeScript that `value` is of type `never`

```js
of().pipe(
   map(value => value = true)
   /// ^^^^^ Warning: Type 'true` is not assignable to type 'never'
);
```

Previous versions of Rxjs (before version 7) used a generic type for this signature, and TypeScript would *infer* the type as a result. So the above code would not raise any warnings. TypeScript would infer that the observable emitted a boolean type (which is not true).

Comment: I understood your example. But webstorm show me this deprecation warning in code example shown above.

Comment: @cyberguycyberguy that is because webstorm is matching the wrong function signature. That's a known issue with webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

`function of<T>()` hasn't been deprecated (per [`of.ts` line 36](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/of.ts#L36) ). However, I'm seeing that tslint is getting this wrong, by raising a warning when I use method signatures that aren't deprecated:

```
WARNING: …/file.ts:39:14 - of is deprecated: remove in v8. Do not use generic arguments directly, allow inference or cast with `as`
```

Until tslint addresses this bug, the workaround is:

```
/* tslint:disable:deprecation */
const response$ = of(response);
/* tslint:enable:deprecation */
...
```